# Possible Perpetual motion?

Tags: electromagnetism, energy-conservation, atomic-physics, perpetual-motion

I have an idea for a perpetual motion machine that I came up with and need answers as to what may be wrong with it.
Consider a molecule made of several atoms, and apply a rotating magnetic field around the molecule. Would it be possible to increase the velocity of that particle to a very high extent?

Comment: I can't really see what you're talking about. Would you mind going into a bit more detail? A few equations would be nice.

Comment: I do not see any relation between the question raised in the title and your text. What makes you think that your scenario has perpetual motion/ violates energy-conservation?

Comment: I am talking whether or not it would be possible to accelerate a molecule using a rotating magnetic field to the extent that it never stops?

Comment: @user131521 Okay, that's easy to do even without a magnetic field. A simple point particle moving through empty space will continue moving forever. When people talk about perpetual motion machines, they usually are referring to ways to create energy from nowhere.

Comment: @user131521 *acceleration* requires energy, while simple linear motion / constant rotation does not.

Answer (score 1):

Electromagnetic fields require energy to create. In fact: (in appropriate units)

\begin{align}
\mathcal{E} & = \frac{1}{2} \left ( E^2 + B^2 \right )
\end{align}

Is the energy density of the electromagnetic field. While I'm not quite sure what you were doing, this energy will account for any accelerations.